# AWS Cognito - authenticate as a user

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Our team has an app and we use Cognito for authentication. In previous projects, we were able to create sessions as a specific user, which helped us to debug issues.

Currently, our app consumes a JWT token for authentication needed by Cognito - would we be able to generate a JWT token for another user (as an admin) in order to debug problems within the app easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tokens issued by Cognito are signed with private AWS keys and the signature within the token can then be verified using public AWS keys. If you could generate a token yourself, with a valid signature, then that would mean that you are in possession of the AWS private keys. I assume that that is not the case, so you cannot arbitrarily create valid Cognito JWTs.

You can of course write test code that ignores the signature or otherwise circumvents proper JWT validation.

Alternatively, as admin, you could create a Cognito user for testing with the properties that you wish to debug and just sign in as that user to get valid JWT tokens in return.

Comment: Thanks -- I learned that it's impossible to modify a JWT token to one's liking.